# sorting alphabetically xml attributes in a php script that displays the information

Tags: javascript, xml, sorting

I have the following xml and html where i'm using a php script that displays the info in the xml, i just want it to be displayed in alphabetical order of the attribute "WORD", instead it displays it in the order of loop, what do i need to change?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->


<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tt.xsl"?>

<LIBRARY>
<TERM>
<EDITBY>giovanni</EDITBY>
<WORD>ciao</WORD>
<LANGUAGE>Italian</LANGUAGE>
<DESCRIPTION>
it means hi
</DESCRIPTION>  
</TERM>


<TERM>
<EDITBY>giacomo</EDITBY>
<WORD>all</WORD>
<LANGUAGE>italian</LANGUAGE>
<DESCRIPTION>
significa tutto
</DESCRIPTION>  
</TERM>

</LIBRARY>
```

and here's the html

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET","res.xml",false);

xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("TERM");for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("WORD")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");

document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("LANGUAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");

document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("DESCRIPTION")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></td>");

document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("EDITBY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: this shows my experience in what i'm doing, hahaha, any help would be greatly appreciated